# How to efficiently store Roll Playing Item properties in Java?

Tags: java, properties, storage

How to efficiently store RPG Item properties in Java?

I'm designing a text based RPG where random items are spawned in when looting chests for example.
Currently I'm storing my Item data in a textfile. When a random item has to be generated a scanner reads the file, collects the values, takes probability in account, and then creates a new object accordingly.
Here is an example of some items of the 'Consumable' class.

The values are listed accordingly:

name, probability, level at which the item gets added to the itempool, weight, value, +health, +damage, Effect

example of textfile:

```
Twinkie 10 1 1 10 10 10 0
Banana 10 1 1 5 5 0 0
Potato 20 1 1 5 5 0 0
Protein_Shake 5 5 1 30 10 10 1
Beer 5 5 1 5 10 10 1
```

If the Effect value equals 0, a new default Consumable gets created with effect 'null'. 
if the Effect value is 1, a function uses a switch(name) statement to find the effect belonging to the item and then
passes the effect as an argument in the 'Consumable constructor'.

I'm certain that this is a very unoriganized and inefficient way to go about this sort of thing. Anyone has a suggestion on how to handle this? I want to do it right.
Should I maybe create an ConsumablePool class where I just create all the items immediatly or store the item information elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to optimize your current task, which seems to be:

```
Consumable nextItem = getRandomConsumable(List<Consumable> candidates);
```

Perhaps you must also choose based on the current level:

```
Consumable nextItem = getRandomConsumable(int level, List<Consumable> candidates);
```

Currently, you state that each time you call `getRandomConsumable()` you generate the list of candidates from a disk file (you seem to have already written this code).  Your instinct is correct.  The 'cost' of this operation is relatively high.  Reading from disk compared to reading from a memory cache of objects will cause poor performance.  Assuming that the disk file does not change during the game, your application should be creating the candidate list once (at startup), and using this List each time the next item must be chosen.

In the case where candidates are based on level, further optimizations can be done.  Consider dividing the candidates by level, such as:

```
List<Consumable> candidates = createCacheFromDisk(); // Run at startup
Map<Integer, List<Consumable>> itemsByLevelMap = candidates .stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Consumable::getLevel));
```

This will further break out the list of candidates into Lists by level, allowing

```
List<Consumable> level1Items = itemsByLevelMap.get(1);
```

This general approach of caching will greatly improve the performance of your application; choosing a random item from a List which has already been generated/cached performs far greater than generating a new List (from disk) each time.

Comment: Thanks for the response, reading the .txt file only once and storing all items in a list is a great idea. Now I'm just wondering if it wouldn't be better to just create a function that doesn't read from text but just creates and stores the objects in the list. This way I can just pass all these arguments in the constructor immediatly and I won't have to use a switch statement to get the corresponding item Effect.

Comment: Your original question does not provide much detail about `Effect`.  If you post more details, I can help optimize the creation and lookup which would avoid the need for a switch statement for each lookup.  It could be that you read from disk, and perform the switch statement only at creation time.

Comment: When consuming the Consumable an effect is applied. Each Consumable has an effect property that stores an object of class Effect. This object has a method apply(). When the player consumes the Consumable this effect gets added to the players activeEffects<Effect> array. Every turn while in combat the apply() method get's called for all effects in the array.

Comment: So an `Effect` object is not stored on the disk, rather created by your program?  How many effect objects are there?  What is their relationship to a random Consumable object (like those stored on the disk)?  Is the effect random, or is there a 1 to 1 relationship that can be assigned at creation time?  Depending on the answer to these questions it would still be possible to create Consumables at start up (and cache them), assigned with the desired effect, so that when a random Consumable is chosen from cache, the effect is present and apply() can be run.